# AWS EC2: error expanding EBS volume partition

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, filesystems, amazon-ebs

I am trying to expand an EBS volume from 120GB to 200GB on an `c5d.xlarge` EC2 instance running Ubuntu. I am following [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html).

So far, I have created a snapshot of the current EBS volume and then expanded it to 200GB.

```bash
sudo lsblk

nvme1n1     259:0    0  93.1G  0 disk
nvme0n1     259:1    0   200G  0 disk
└─nvme0n1p1 259:2    0   120G  0 part /
```

Following the guide, I have tried to expand the `nvme0n1p1` partition to 200GB:

```bash
sudo growpart /dev/nvme0n1p1 1

WARN: unknown label
failed [sfd_dump:1] sfdisk --unit=S --dump /dev/nvme0n1p1
sfdisk: /dev/nvme0n1p1: does not contain a recognized partition table
FAILED: failed to dump sfdisk info for /dev/nvme0n1p1
```

It seems the partition is not recognized.

I have also tried with `resize2fs` command, but it doesn't do anything:

```bash
sudo resize2fs /dev/nvme0n1p1

resize2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
The filesystem is already 31457019 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

Any idea how can I make the partition to expand to the correct size?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually the `growpart` command was wrong. It must follow the syntax `growpart path/to/device_name partition_number`, so the right command is:

```bash
sudo growpart /dev/nvme0n1 1
```

Answer (score -1):

resize2fs won't work because you're dealing with an xfs file system rather than ext4.

Instead after your growpart, you need to run this command to completely resize your xfs file system:

```
xfs_growfs -d /

df -hT

Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs       devtmpfs  465M     0  465M   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     473M     0  473M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     473M   13M  460M   3% /run
tmpfs          tmpfs     473M     0  473M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p1 xfs        12G  2.6G  9.5G  22% /
tmpfs          tmpfs      95M     0   95M   0% /run/user/0
```